# Detecting collisions between a sphere and triangle

Tags: c++, math, collision-detection, glm-math

I am trying to detect collision between a sphere and a triangle in C++ and OpenGL but I am having trouble. I got this method from the book Real Time Collsion Detection, however this is setting off a lot of false flags and something is not working. How exactly do I detect collisions between a sphere and a triangle?

Here is what I tired in my code, the function takes in the spheres position, radius, and the 3 triangle vertices:

```
bool CollisionHelper::isSphereIntersectingTriangle(glm::vec3 sphere, float radius, glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
    float dist1 = glm::sqrt((sphere.x - tri1.x) * (sphere.x - tri1.x) + (sphere.y - tri1.y) * (sphere.y - tri1.y) + (sphere.z - tri1.z) * (sphere.z - tri1.z));
    float dist2 = glm::sqrt((sphere.x - tri2.x) * (sphere.x - tri2.x) + (sphere.y - tri2.y) * (sphere.y - tri2.y) + (sphere.z - tri2.z) * (sphere.z - tri2.z));
    float dist3 = glm::sqrt((sphere.x - tri3.x) * (sphere.x - tri3.x) + (sphere.y - tri3.y) * (sphere.y - tri3.y) + (sphere.z - tri3.z) * (sphere.z - tri3.z));
    float closestDist = glm::min(glm::min(dist1, dist2), dist3);
    glm::vec3 v;
    if (closestDist == dist1)
        v = tri1 - sphere;
    else if (closestDist == dist2)
        v = tri2 - sphere;
    else (closestDist == dist3)
        v = tri3 - sphere;
    return glm::dot(v, v) <= radius * radius;
}
```

Comment: I would first use variables to stores intermediate results. The code is very hard to read as-is and is liable of hiding simple mistakes.

Comment: It seems like you are just checking for intersection between the sphere and any of its vertices. This fails if the sphere is smaller than a certain size as it could pass between these points.

Comment: How exactly would I check the edges/face?

Comment: @user324093252 - by checking for the intersection between a circle and any of the three line segments, between its vertices.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: @enhzflep That has the same problem, a small sphere could pass between the edges.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Well spotted. I'd seemingly missed the 3d aspect when seeing the word triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the tests that I would perform.
First I'd transform the coordinates such that the center of the sphere is (0,0,0).
Easiest to check is if one of the corners is inside.
Next is to check if one of the edges is cutting.
Finally I would test whether the sphere passes the plane without cutting the edges.
To do so I'd calculate the orthogonal distance of the plane, given by the triangle, to the origin. This also gives the point on the plane, where the surface normal starts. If this is shorter than the radius and within the triangle perimeter, done.

**Edit**

Here some python code to clarify

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1, projection='3d' )

# Make data
u = np.linspace( 0, .5 * np.pi, 15 )
v = np.linspace( 0, .5 * np.pi, 15 )

### radius is 1 but problem can be scaled
R = 1
x = R * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v) )
y = R * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v) )
z = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u) ), np.cos(v) )

"""
Random Test
"""
# ~scale = 3
# ~A = np.array( (
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random() ) 
# ~)
# ~B = np.array( (
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random() ) 
# ~)
# ~C = np.array( (
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random(), 
    # ~scale * np.random.random() ) 
# ~)

"""
TestCases
"""
if 0: #definitive outside
    A = np.array( [ 1.3, 0.4, 0.6 ] )
    B = np.array( [ 1.3, 1.4, 0.6 ] )
    C = np.array( [ 1.3, 0.4, 1.6 ] )
if 0: # outside but plane normal inside
    A = np.array( [ 1.3, 0.4, 0.6 ] )
    B = np.array( [ 0.7, 1.4, 0.6 ] )
    C = np.array( [ 1.8, 0.4, 1.0 ] )
if 0: # cutting edge
    A = np.array( [ 1.1, 0.0, 0.1 ] )
    B = np.array( [ 0.1, 1.4, -0.2 ] )
    C = np.array( [ 1.8, 0.4, 1.0 ] )
if 1: # cutting plane
    A = np.array( [ 1.4, 0.0, 0.1 ] )
    B = np.array( [ 0.1, 1.4, -0.2 ] )
    C = np.array( [ -0.03, 0.1, 2.0 ] )

"""
Most simple check:
is one of the vertices indside
"""

print np.linalg.norm( A ), np.linalg.norm( A ) < R 
print np.linalg.norm( B ), np.linalg.norm( B ) < R 
print np.linalg.norm( C ), np.linalg.norm( C ) < R 

"""
checking if one edge cuts the sphere
this uses simple derivatives of the distance function
"""
for F,G in [ ( B, A ), (C, B), (A, C)]:
    a =  F - G
    s = -np.dot( a, G )/ np.dot( a, a )
    print "s: ", s, s > 0 and s < 1
    d  = np.linalg.norm( G + s * a )
    print "d: ", d,  d < R
    ### if both are true, it is cutting
    print "---------"

"""
checking if the sphere cuts the area
e.g in the extreme case of (but not restricted to) a sphere
passing through
"""
a = B - A
c = C - A
aa = np.dot( a, a)
cc = np.dot( c, c)
ac = np.dot( a, c)
aA = np.dot( a, A)
cA = np.dot( c, A)

MI = np.array( [
    np.array([ cc, -ac ] ),
    np.array([ -ac, aa ] )
])
MI /= ( aa * cc - ac**2 ) ### div by det

st = np.dot( MI, [ -aA, -cA ] )
s=st[0]
t=st[1]
P = A + s * a + t * c

"""
If this is larger than R we can stop here
if otherwise we detect if P inside triangle by repeating the stuff 
above with respect to B
"""
a2 = A - B
c2 = C - B
aa2 = np.dot( a2, a2 )
cc2 = np.dot( c2, c2 )
ac2 = np.dot( a2, c2 )
aB2 = np.dot( a2, B )
cB2 = np.dot( c2, B )

MI2 = np.array( [
    np.array([ +cc2, -ac2 ] ),
    np.array([ -ac2, +aa2 ] )
])
MI2 /= ( aa2 * cc2 - ac2**2 ) 
uv = np.dot( MI2, [ -aB2, -cB2 ] )
u = uv[0]
v = uv[1]
P2 = B + u * a2 + v * c2

print "must be identical"
print P, np.linalg.norm( P ) < R
print P2, np.linalg.norm( P2 ) < R

print "is inside if all 4 are positive"
print s, t, u, v



### finally some plotting
verts = [ [ A, B, C  ] ]
srf = Poly3DCollection( verts, alpha=.9, facecolor='#800000' )

ax.plot_wireframe( x, y, z, color='b' )
ax.plot( [ 0, P[0] ], [ 0, P[1] ], [ 0, P[2] ] )
ax.add_collection3d(srf)
ax.set_xlim( [-0.5, 2 ] )
ax.set_ylim( [-0.5, 2 ] )
ax.set_zlim( [-0.5, 2 ] )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Python example would be awesome if you are able too, implementation is always the trickiest part of these complex math problems

Comment: @user324093252 there you go